# Why is date.dateByAddingTimeInterval(seconds) off by 1 hour?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Why is .dateByAddingTimeInterval() returning 1 hour off difference?  Daylight savings is not in effect currently so this should not affect it. What am I doing wrong?

http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=4&d1=25&y1=2011&m2=1&d2=1&y2=2043&h1=0&i1=0&s1=0&h2=1&i2=46&s2=40

```
import Foundation

struct Gigasecond{

        static func newDate(input:String, format:String = "yyyy-MM-dd" ) -> NSDate{
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
            return dateFormatter.dateFromString(input) ?? NSDate.distantFuture() as NSDate
        }

        static func from(dateInString:String) -> NSDate{

            var dateIn = newDate(dateInString)

            return dateIn.dateByAddingTimeInterval(1_000_000_000)

        }

    }

    let newDate23 = Gigasecond.newDate("2043-01-01T01:46:40", format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    println(Gigasecond.from("2011-4-25").timeIntervalSinceDate(newDate23)) //-3600.0  or 1 hour ( 60*60 )
```

Comment: What tells you it's off by an hour??

Comment: Add the output to the question.

Comment: Running your code I get the output 999,993,600, which differs from 1,000,000,000  precisely by 6400 (= 1 hour, 46 minutes and 40 seconds). This is exactly the time that you have specified in "2011-4-25T01:46:40", but not in "2011-4-25".

Comment: Typo fixed. The link shows the dates difference.

Comment: If you claim there's a difference, show us the results.  (And don't link to some odd site and claim that's the results from your program.)

Comment: Sorry about the typos guys. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you explicitly set the timeZone formatter?

```
struct Gigasecond{

    static func newDate(input:String, format:String = "yyyy-MM-dd" ) -> NSDate{
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

        // Explicitly set the time Zone for the formatter
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(input) ?? NSDate.distantFuture() as NSDate
    }

    static func from(dateInString:String) -> NSDate{

        var dateIn = newDate(dateInString)

        return dateIn.dateByAddingTimeInterval(1_000_000_000)

    }

}

let newDate23 = Gigasecond.newDate("2011-4-25T01:46:40", format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
println(Gigasecond.from("2011-4-25").timeIntervalSinceDate(newDate23))
```

Comment: Sorry I had I typo. I tried using 0 for the timezone and that did not change anything.

Comment: @masters3d: I get -3600.0 for your updated code, but 0.0 if the timezone is set to GMT as suggested here.

Comment: Infect afaik `NSDateFormatter` by default uses localized timeZone, unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: This worked, Thank you. I was trying to set the timezone with         dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.\(Z)" where Z was = 0 but that did not work